# Buisld String based on multiple propety values of an object

Tags: java

I have an object which has three Boolean values and based on their values, I have to build a string. Right now a the method I am using is this:

```
if(a)
    string.append("a");
if(string.len!=0) {
    if(b) {
        if(c) {
            string.append(", ").append("b").append(" and ").append("c");
        }
        else {
            string.append(" and ").append("b");
        }
    }
    else {
        //check for c and add "and" string appropriately
    }
}

// then again an else part when string length is not zero and I check these values again
```

Is there a better way to do this?

This code worked for me

```
final String result = Arrays.asList(values).stream()
            .filter(o -> o != null)
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) 
            .replaceAll(", (a|b|c)$", " and $1");
```

Comment: What `spring-mvc` has to do with this?

Comment: Just to tell I am working on Java spring mvc

Comment: You might also be working on few more technologies for the same project, but this question does not include anything related to `spring-mvc`, so it is irrelevant.

Comment: I just wanted to know if there is anything like java 8 stream to help me do this easily. That is why I included java spring

Comment: You can create a stream using Stream.of(a, b, c) and the collect is using a custom collector, in which you can check if each item is true/false and build the final string accordingly (check out the collect method that takes a supplier, accumulator and combiner)

Comment: @AshutoshA I will try. Thanks!

Comment: I just have a question...at the beginning you are appending the string `"a"` and then you append the boolean values of `b` and `c`. This would print something like: `"a", true and true`. Is this the expected result or is it a typo?

Comment: @payloc yes it is a typo. Actually I have three databases and I have a flag to say in the user object which says if he exists in which all databases. So based on which db he exists, I want to print a string user exist in database a, b and c. For example if a user exist in database A and B i have print user will be updated to A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to output something like `a, b and c` (see my comment) this would do the trick:

```
final boolean a = true, b = true, c = true;
final String[] values = new String[] {a ? "a" : null, b ? "b" : null, c ? "c" : null};
final String result = Arrays.asList(values).stream()
        .filter(o -> o != null) // discard all null (false) values in the list
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) // join all elements by concatenating with ','
        .replaceAll(", (a|b|c)$", " and $1"); // replace last ',' with 'and'
```

Performance wise this will probably be a little worse than your code as its first building a comma separated string and replacing the last `,` with an `and` but in your case the difference should be negligible.

Comment: can you please tell me what you have done inside replace all portion of stream. I have multiple flags to check which point to same database so my final string looks like a,a,b,b and c where I want a, b and c.

Comment: can you please tell me what you have done inside replace all portion of stream. I have multiple flags to check which point to same database so my final string looks like a,a,b,b and c where I want a, b and c.

Comment: `“, (a|b|c)$“` is a simple regular expression that matches a comma followed by a single character either a, b or c and the end of the string ($). The matched substring is replaced with ` and ` followed by everything that matched the first marching group. That is either a, b or c. What do you mean by “multiple flags to check” in your question you mentioned three booleans only...

Comment: I applied distinct to get the distinct values. Thanks a lot for the help!   
             final String result = Arrays.asList(values).stream()
                .filter(o -> o != null)
                .distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) 
                .replaceAll(", (a|b|c)$", " and $1");

Answer (score 0):

I did not really get what output you wish, so I'll propose a few code snippets.

Please, note: my solution only works if you are willing to create a list from your `boolean` values.

So if you have *(let's add a few more...)*:

```
boolean a = true;
boolean b = false;
boolean c = true;
boolean d = false;
boolean e = false;
boolean f = true;
boolean g = true;
boolean h = true;
boolean i = false;
boolean j = true;
```

The first step is to create a `List<Boolean>`

```
final List<Boolean> values = Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j);
```

Let's see now different cases:

**You want to print only `true` values**

```
String output1 = values.stream()    // create stream
            .filter(bool -> bool)       // accept only true values
            .map(Object::toString)     // transform to string 
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")); // append everything with a comma
```

Output: `true, true, true, true, true, true`

But this does not mean anything. You do not know which values are `true`, so this probably isn't what you want.

**You want to print only `true` values with the index**:

```
final String output2 = IntStream.range(0, values.size())    // generate integers from 0 to N
            .filter(values::get)                                // get only positives
            .mapToObj(idx -> idx + ": " + values.get(idx))      // generate string 'n: bool'
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));         // append
```

Output: `0: true, 2: true, 5: true, 6: true, 7: true, 9: true`

**You probably want the `char` value instead of an `integer` index**

When you `mapToObj` you can covert the `integer` index to an `ASCII` char

```
.mapToObj(idx -> Character.valueOf((char) (97 + idx)).toString() + ": " + values.get(idx))
```

Output: `a: true, c: true, f: true, g: true, h: true, j: true`

**You only want to print the indexes/chars the are true**

```
final String output3 = IntStream.range(0, values.size())
            .filter(values::get)
            .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Output: `0, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9`

**Or,** with `.mapToObj(idx -> Character.valueOf((char) (97 + idx)).toString())`

Output: `a, c, f, g, h, j`

---

Now the last part, is the change the last `,` into an `and` literal.

I couldn't come up with anything other than:

```
int lastComma = output3.lastIndexOf(",");
String newOuput = new StringBuilder(output3).replace(lastComma, lastComma + 2, " and ").toString();
```

Output: `0, 2, 5, 6, 7 and 9`